# Logistic Regression: how to reduce bias in data

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, prediction, bias

I have a logistic regression model and my main goal is to predict probability of surviving using explanatory variables like age, gender etc. Each row in my data represents an individual and columns are age (an integer number), gender (M, F), exposure time i.e. how long a particular individual is exposed to the risk of dying (a number between [0,1]) and a response variable taking values of 0 or 1 to indicate death/alive. I used exposure time as weights for each observation.
The data I am considering contains individual data from different countries. My model does not allow any country specific covariate to be included.
Unfortunately, one country (e.g. country A) dominates the data significantly in terms of both 0's and 1's to the extent that almost **80%** of my data is coming from country A. When I fit the logistic regression, the model performs well in country A (as expected) but not that well over other countries.

**Q:** I would like to reduce the effect of country A in my model so that it performs OK but over all countries. Could anyone tell me what options do I have? As I said, I already used weights in the model.

**My thought**: Maybe I can split data for country A into disjoint parts and combine each part to other countries and fit multiple logistic regression? Once I obtained these models, I take the average of estimated coefficients in each model to come up with a single model for the sake of predicting probability of surviving.

Comment: Well, if the preponderance of country A in your data causes your model not to work well in other countries, it sounds as if there are country-specific effects (otherwise, the passport of your subjects would not matter). So a well-specified model *should* include countries, possibly in interaction with other covariates. Why does your model not allow this?

Comment: Thanks Stephan. One of the main goals of developing this model is to collect information from different countries and then being able to predict survival probabilities without actually knowing the country. Unfortunately, I cannot have a country specific effect in the model.

Comment: Hm. It sounds like a hierarchical or random effects model might be useful, with country as a random effect. Plus possibly reweighting or resampling your training data so it better reflects the demographics of the test set. If that is possible.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. If I setup a GLMM with country as a random effect, shouldn't I know the country when predicting?

Comment: in mixed or hierarchical models, you can predict on different levels. If you know the new country, you can include that. If you don't, the predictions will use the average effect across countries, since you do not specify it. How this is done specifically depends on your software.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephan.